# Compress Guid's in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, compression

Any simple algo to compress/encode the guid string into a smaller string representation and then decode it back to guid. Any javascript code available for it.

Eg. 0a0a8907-40b9-4e81-8c4d-d01af26efb78 is using 36 characters. Can i reduce to string representation with around 20-24 characters...

Comment: Why? --- And where / how is it being used?

Comment: I am writing a long of string of GUIDs seperated by semicolons into a QR code. I just need to reduce the size of this string....

Comment: Since GUIDs are more or less random, or at least don't pursue obvious patterns, I don't think compression would be advantageous at all. Have you tested the "compressibility" of your strings?

Comment: Since quids are always the same length, I don't see why you need semicolons.

Comment: My string can containg random text as well.. so i have to separate it with some kind of separator..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [library](http://en.1mu.info/tools/hexbase64.js) which is able to convert HEX to BASE64 and backwards. 
You basically need to strip every hyphen from the GUID and encode it:

```
var guid = "0a0a8907-40b9-4e81-8c4d-d01af26efb78";
var encoded = guid.replace(/-/g, "");
encoded = hexToBase64(encoded);
```

The receicing end then can decode it and put it back together:

```
var chunks = [];
chunks.push( decoded.substring(0, 8) );
chunks.push( decoded.substring(8, 12) );
chunks.push( decoded.substring(12, 16) );
chunks.push( decoded.substring(16, 20) );
chunks.push( decoded.substring(20) );
decoded = chunks.join("-");
```

The encoded version of your example GUID is `CgqJB0C5ToGMTdAa8m77eA==` and 24 characters long.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4Zch/2/) for a working example.

Comment: yeah.. the decoded string wasnt correct.. probably i was looking at it to correct it... Thanks

Comment: @Jason Should be working now finally. Check the updated fiddle (Update 2)

Comment: What will be equivalent of this code in C#.. especially for function hexToBase64 .. if u r aware of it..

Comment: I see that the encoded string has always == appended at end.. so what i can do is remove these while encoding... and i will get 22 characters.. and before decoding i will append == ..... hope it will work in all scenarios..

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple routine that doesn't need an external library and stores the data in 12-24 actual bytes:

```
function encode(s){
  return s.split("-").map(function(a,b,c){ 
   return a.split(/(\w{4})/).filter(Boolean).map(function(aa,bb,cc){
               return  String.fromCharCode(parseInt(aa, 16))
          }).join("");
  }).join("|");
}


function decode(s){
  return s.split("|").map(function(a){     
     return a.split("").map(function(aa){return String("0"+aa.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4) }).join("")
  }).join("-");
}



var guid = "0a0a8907-40b9-4e81-8c4d-d01af26efb78"; //36 chars
var encoded=encode(guid); //=== "ਊ複|䂹|亁|豍|퀚ﭸ"
var guid2=decode(encoded);

alert([guid, guid2, encoded].join("\n"));

/* shows:
 0a0a8907-40b9-4e81-8c4d-d01af26efb78
 0a0a8907-40b9-4e81-8c4d-d01af26efb78
 ਊ複|䂹|亁|豍|퀚ﭸ
 12b
*/
```

this makes good use of localStorage, since it can store wide chars un-encoded. If you have to break out into ascii, they you're wasting time and space with this routine...

Comment: Thanks Dandavis.. it is good for local storage.. but as I have to write data on QR code.. this encoded string will take lot of space there..

Answer (score 0):

Convert the hex values to integers in 32 bit chunks then reencode the resulting string using base 64.